# r - Merge two dataframes in master/detail hierarchy

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data.frames, one represents the directed connection of two sites in my system, for example below site a1 (looking at the rows) is connected to site d1 but not the other way around. And d1 is connected to itself and d2.

```
>connections=read.table("file1")
>connections
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 Site
1  0  1  0  0  0   a1
2  0  1  1  0  0   d1
3  0  1  1  1  1   d2
4  1  0  0  0  0   d3
5  0  0  0  0  0   f1
```

What has been really hard for me is to write this connections in terms of the subunits of each site, each sites are composed of 5 subunits, as seen in my summary file below, each subunit id is unique.

```
  > subunits=read.table("file2")
  > subunits
      Site minID maxId
    1   a1     0     4
    2   d1     5     9
    3   d2    10    14
    4   d3    15    19 
    5   f1    20    24
```

My goal is to create a detail table of connections by subunit , the result should look something like

```
site subunit numconnections conectionids…
a1 0 5 5 6 7 8 9
a1 1 5 5 6 7 8 9
a1 2 5 5 6 7 8 9
a1 3 5 5 6 7 8 9
a1 4 5 5 6 7 8 9
d1 5 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
d1 6 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
d1 7 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
d1 8 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
d1 9 10 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
d2 10 20 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
d2 11 20 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
d2 12 20 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
d2 13 20 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
d2 14 20 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
d3 15 5 0 1 2 3 4
d3 16 5 0 1 2 3 4
d3 17 5 0 1 2 3 4
d3 18 5 0 1 2 3 4
d3 19 5 0 1 2 3 4
f1 20 0
f1 21 0
f1 22 0
f1 23 0
f1 24 0

…
```

This is file1 and file2

file1

```
"V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "Site"
"1" 0 1 0 0 0 "a1"
"2" 0 1 1 0 0 "d1"
"3" 0 1 1 1 1 "d2"
"4" 1 0 0 0 0 "d3"
"5" 0 0 0 0 0 "f1"
```

file2

```
"Site" "minID" "maxId"
"1" "a1" 0 4
"2" "d1" 5 9
"3" "d2" 10 14
"4" "d3" 15 19
"5" "f1" 20 24
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can consider using a list, and access the relevant information from there, here is one solution.

1. Create your data frames:

---

```
connections <- data.frame(  c(0,0,0,1,0), c(1,1,1,0,0), c(0,1,1,0,0), c(0,0,1,0,0), c(0,0,1,0,0), c("a1", "d1", "d2", "d3", "f1") )

# here I build up the df as in your example but then show how to 
# rearrange it a bit so it is easier to use later

colnames(connections) <-c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "Site")
colnames(connections) <- c("a1", "d1", "d2", "d3", "f1")
row.names(connections) <- c("a1", "d1", "d2", "d3", "f1")
connections <- connections[,-6]

subunits <- data.frame(c("a1", "d1", "d2", "d3", "f1"), c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20), c(4,9,14,19,24 ))
colnames(subunits) <- c("Site", "minID", "maxId")
row.names(subunits) <- c("a1", "d1", "d2", "d3", "f1")
subunits <- subunits[,-1]
```

2. Create a list of what's connected to what

---

```
site <- apply(X = connections, 1, FUN = function(x) which(x == 1))
```

3. Make a list of subunits - this will be useful when getting connection ids

---

```
subunit <-  t(apply(subunits, 1, function(x) seq(x[1], x[2]) ))
```

4. Get a list `numconnections` with the number of connections

---

```
# here I switch to a loop rather than apply as I think it will be more readable 

numconnections <- vector("list", length(names(site)))
names(numconnections) <- names(site)
for(i in 1:length(names(site))){
  nc <- sum(names(site[[i]]) %in% row.names(subunit) * length(site))
  numconnections[[i]] <- nc

}
```

5. Finally, for each subunit get all the connection ids

---

```
conectionids <- vector("list",  length(names(site)))
for(i in 1:length(names(site))){

  names(conectionids)[[i]] <- names(site)[i]
    for(j in 1:length(names(site[[i]]))){
      conectionids[[i]] <- c(conectionids[[i]], subunit[which( row.names(subunit) %in% names(site[[i]])[j]), ])
    }

}
```

From here you could query the relevant information or build up a data frame or combine all the information in a list (list if probably best).